# Table field value & foreign key - LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working with mysql `LOAD DATA INFILE` to insert csv values into a table named `test`. Everything so far so good until now when things got a little more complex. I have another table `occupations` which holds `occupation_id` which I am using as foreign key inside the table `test`. The original csv file only comes with the following fields `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Age`, `Date Of Birth` and `Occupation` (see example below with values). I  would like to figure the `occupation_id` based on the csv text field `Occupation`. How could it be possible?

Column titles in `csv file` with their respective values

```
+------------+-----------+-----+---------------+------------+
| First Name | Last Name | Age | Date of Birth | Occupation |
+------------+-----------+-----+---------------+------------+
| Lionel     | Messi     |  27 | 6/24/1987     | Soccer     |
| Michael    | Jordan    |  51 | 2/17/1963     | Basketball |
| Lebron     | James     |  30 | 12/30/1984    | Actor      |
+------------+-----------+-----+---------------+------------+
```

table `occupation`

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| occupation_id | occupation_name |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             1 | Basketball      |
|             2 | Soccer          |
|             3 | Actor           |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

results after csv insert to table `test`

```
+------------+-----------+-----+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| first_name | last_name | age |    dob      | occupation_id | occupation_name |
+------------+-----------+-----+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Lionel     | Messi     |  27 | 1987-06-24  |             2 | Soccer          |
| Michael    | Jordan    |  51 | 1963-02-17  |             1 | Basketball      |
| Lebron     | James     |  30 | 1984-30-12  |             3 | Actor           |
+------------+-----------+-----+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

PHP/SQL - my query so far

```
$db_insert = $db_con->prepare("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filename."'
    INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@column1, @column2, @column3, @column4, @column5)
    SET first_name=@column1, last_name=@column2, age=@column3, dob = STR_TO_DATE(@column4, '%m/%d/%Y'), occupation=@column5
");
$db_insert->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to do this in the `LOAD DATA` statement. In theory you can do a subquery in a `LOAD DATA` statement to look up the respective `occupation_id`, but even if you could, it would hurt the performance of the bulk loading.

Here's how it would look, but I expect performance to be terrible if you load more than a trivial number of rows:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 't.csv'
INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@column1, @column2, @column3, @column4, @column5)
SET first_name=@column1, last_name=@column2, age=@column3,
  dob = STR_TO_DATE(@column4, '%m/%d/%Y'), occupation=@column5, 
  occupation_id=(SELECT occupation_id FROM occupation WHERE occupation_name=@column5 LIMIT 1);
```

Instead, I'd do the LOAD DATA and leave the `occupation_id` empty. Then after the `LOAD DATA` is finished, run an `UPDATE` joined to the other table:

```
UPDATE test JOIN occupation ON test.occupation = occupation.occupation_name
SET test.occupation_id = occupation.occupation_id;
```

Comment: +1 This is a great approach. If doing it all in the `LOAD DATA` I get the following error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'occupation_name' in 'field lis`

Comment: I have edited the above hoping to match the column names you listed.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would get rid of the field `test.occupation_name`

Then, you can do it in two steps:

1. Load the CSV file as is, with `LOAD DATA`, into a table resembling the csv structure. Let's call it `test_csv`, and use field names compatible with those of `test`
2. Perform the following:

.

```
INSERT INTO test 
SELECT tc.first_name, tc.last_name, tc.age, tc.dob, o.occupation_id
FROM test_csv tc
JOIN occupation o ON (tc.occupation_name=o.occupation_name)
```

You will end up with table `test` referencing the occupations in table `occupations`

Hope this helps.